# Creating THREE.Points return Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is a part of the code. I tested the `geometry` and `material` variables on both return values. Removing these variables, the error disappear.

```
var actionZ = 0;
var rotationA = 1.1;
var movementSpeed = 1;
var totalObjects = 40000;
var rotated = false;
var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'home-background';
document.body.appendChild( container );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,1, 2000)
camera.position.z = 2000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(camera);
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x00b4f1, 0.0003 );
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < totalObjects; i ++) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.random()*40000-20000;
  vertex.y = Math.random()*7000-3500;
  vertex.z = Math.random()*7000-3500;
  geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}

var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 3, color: 0x00b4f1});
var particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
```

Comment: your question is vague. Please show what THREE is and where it is defined. Show your related html also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug in `R106` when creating `THREE.Points` with `THREE.Geometry`. You can avoid the issue by using `THREE.BufferGeometry` or by using the latest `dev` version. `R107` will be released at the end of July. Here is the related PR that fixed the issue:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/16932