# Three.js Objects not showing, there is only a black screen shown

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I've been having this similar issue with a few of my other three.js codes as well. I set up the js within html but the objects are not showing up. There's just a black screen showing up when I run the file.

The file is supposed to show rain drops falling off the sky when it is run.
I used atom to build it. I tried html preview on atom, atom live server internet explorer chrome and they all showed the same black screen when i tried running it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <title>RAIN ON ME BABY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    let scene,camera, renderer, cloudParticles = [], flash, rain, rainGeo, rainCount = 15000;
    function init() {
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
      camera.position.z = 1;
      camera.rotation.x = 1.16;
      camera.rotation.y = -0.12;
      camera.rotation.z = 0.27;
      ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
      scene.add(ambient);

      directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
      directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1);
      scene.add(directionalLight);

      flash = new THREE.PointLight(0x062d89, 30, 500 ,1.7);
      flash.position.set(200,300,100);
      scene.add(flash);

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x11111f, 0.002);
      renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      rainGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
      for(let i=0;i<rainCount;i++) {
        rainDrop = new THREE.Vector3(
          Math.random() * 400 -200,
          Math.random() * 500 - 250,
          Math.random() * 400 - 200
        );
        rainDrop.velocity = {};
        rainDrop.velocity = 0;
        rainGeo.vertices.push(rainDrop);
      }
      rainMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        size: 0.1,
        transparent: true
      });
      rain = new THREE.Points(rainGeo,rainMaterial);
      scene.add(rain);
      let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
      loader.load("smoke.png", function(texture){
        cloudGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500,500);
        cloudMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          map: texture,
          transparent: true
        });
        for(let p=0; p<25; p++) {
          let cloud = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeo,cloudMaterial);
          cloud.position.set(
            Math.random()*800 -400,
            500,
            Math.random()*500 - 450
          );
          cloud.rotation.x = 1.16;
          cloud.rotation.y = -0.12;
          cloud.rotation.z = Math.random()*360;
          cloud.material.opacity = 0.6;
          cloudParticles.push(cloud);
          scene.add(cloud);
        }
        animate();
      });
    }
    function animate() {
      cloudParticles.forEach(p => {
        p.rotation.z -=0.002;
      });
      rainGeo.vertices.forEach(p => {
        p.velocity -= 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.1;
        p.y += p.velocity;
        if (p.y < -200) {
          p.y = 200;
          p.velocity = 0;
        }
      });
      rainGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
      rain.rotation.y +=0.002;
      if(Math.random() > 0.93 || flash.power > 100) {
        if(flash.power < 100)
          flash.position.set(
            Math.random()*400,
            300 + Math.random() *200,
            100
          );
        flash.power = 50 + Math.random() * 500;
      }
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is actually a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57114890/5250847

With `R016`, it's not possible to create `THREE.Points` with `THREE.Geometry`. This is already fixed in `dev` and eventually with the next release `R107` at the end of July.

I've copied your code to the following fiddle and replaced the build file with the current `dev` version which fixes the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/76tw2jL0/

BTW: The best fix is actually the usage of `THREE.BufferGeometry`.